# Why when I set an image to the cursor, it doesn't work?

Tags: java, image, swing, mouse-cursor

I'm new in Java and I have a problem trying set an image to the cursor. I'm using a `BufferedImage` and `Graphics.drawImage` but it is only drawing a color of the image and not the full png image.

Here is my code:

```
/*The images List*/
iconsBet.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/ChipType"+ String.valueOf(maxChipBet+1) +".png")));
/*The images List*/

BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(iconsBet.get(0).getWidth(), iconsBet.get(0).getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
Graphics graphicsCursorIcon = output.getGraphics();

int count = 0;
for(BufferedImage icon : iconsBet)
{                
   graphicsCursorIcon.drawImage(icon, 0, count*10, null);
   count++;
}

graphicsCursorIcon.dispose();
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(output , new Point(mainPanel.getX(), mainPanel.getY()), "img");
mainPanel.setCursor(c);
```

The image: [This is one image from the group of images that I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89MA.png)

[image]

The program only draw a red circle and not the png image.

I already tried use all the `BufferedImage` types, but yet doesn't work.
Could you please help me with this? What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: On windows, you are restrict to a cursor size of 32x32 - it might have changed, but that was the case under Windows 7/Java 7

Comment: You are drawing your images on top of each other.
Are you sure they have proper transparency?
May be the last image completely overpaints all the previous ones.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). Though in this case, you might hot-link to the image embedded in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MCVE works here, though it shrinks the cursor down to a smaller size.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.URL;

public class CustomImageCursor {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    CustomImageCursor() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(40, 400, 40, 40));

        try {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(
                    new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89MA.png"));
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(bi, new Point(0, 0), "img");
            ui.setCursor(c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                CustomImageCursor o = new CustomImageCursor();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you misinterpreted the second argument of [Toolkit.createCustomCursor(Image cursor, Point hotSpot, String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor-java.awt.Image-java.awt.Point-java.lang.String-):

> `hotSpot` - the X and Y of the large cursor's hot spot;
>   the hotSpot values must be less than the Dimension returned by getBestCursorSize

The `hotspot` is meant relative to the top-left corner of the cursor image,
not to the top-left corner of the panel.
So, instead of

```
new Point(mainPanel.getX(), mainPanel.getY())
```

just try

```
new Point(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you're right, i misinterpreted that. Already i corrected it, but it isn't the reason of my problem. Because i need only copy the button image and draw it on the cursor, but it only draw a circle with a color and not the full PNG image.
Thank you very much for you observation.

Comment: @DarthHollow Then there is still a problem with your images. You should add these to your question to get good answers.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, already i put the image in the question.

Comment: @DarthHollow Your image is quite large (300x298). I don't know if that would cause problems. But typical cursor images are not larger than 32x32.